# how do i recover deleted files from the command git rm -r * with files that were commited but wasnt pushed

Tags: git, github, git-rm

i accidentally removed file from his repository in github (and i had a lot of changes in some of my files, because i didn't push them yet), and after i remote back to the same repository in github -iv'e added the files again, i made a commit to the files, and when i tried to push i got this error - 
"fatal: You are not currently on a branch."
I tried to "fix" the situation, and made the command - 
"git rm -r *"
and ALL my the content of the file got deleted from my computer.
I really dont know what to do now and how do i recover those files back 
(just a reminder - the current branch on github is not updated to my last commit - because no push was made)

Comment: Did you get the "fatal: You are not currently on a branch" error when doing `git commit` or `git push`? I imagine you got it when trying to commit and hence didn't actually commit your changes.

Comment: Also, what did you expect to achieve with `git rm -r *`?

Comment: It was when i tried to do git push.

Comment: @GabrielStaples i searched for an answer online and somehow iv'e seen this solution and just didn't think on the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

You can get them back with `git checkout -- filepath`

```
git checkout -- file1 file2
```

And so on. They will be checked out as they were on HEAD.

Comment: even though the i got those messages - "HEAD detached from 'f17603c'"?

Comment: That's fine. A branch is just a pointer to a revision. HEAD is just a (special) pointer to a revision. And you got the error about not being on a branch because you are on **detached HEAD**, that's why git could not know what you wanted to push in the first place.

Comment: this is what happened after i did the rm command -
PS C:\wamp64\www\Dashboard-api\lucy-dashboard-server> git commit -m "your comment"
[detached HEAD 27cdf97] your comment
 64 files changed, 5703 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 .gitignore
 delete mode 100644 Procfile
 and so on to all the rest of the files in that file.

Comment: i got this error when tried to recover file with your command - 
"error: pathspec 'controllers/contact.js' did not match any file(s) known to git"

Comment: Oh... sure, the removal is already committed. Try with `git checkout HEAD~ -- file1 file2`.

Comment: You are a true life saver.
Thank you so much!